# NULL value passed as symbol address with Rcpp functions

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, r-package, rcpparmadillo

I apologize if this question is quite silly as I am new to Rcpp. I have built a package from Rcpp but when I installed it, I found all functions related to Rcpp will return the following type of error message:
Error in .Call(<pointer: 0x0>, M) : NULL value passed as symbol address

Here is an example:

getEigenValue.cpp

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]

arma::vec getEigenValue(arma::mat M) {
  arma::vec eigval;
  arma::mat eigvec;
  
  eig_sym(eigval, eigvec, M);
  return eigval;
};
```

RcppExports.cpp

```
// getEigenValue
arma::vec getEigenValue(arma::mat M);
RcppExport SEXP _mypackage_getEigenValue(SEXP MSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< arma::mat >::type M(MSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(getEigenValue(M));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}
```

RcppExports.R

```
getEigenValue <- function(M) {
    .Call(`_mypackage_getEigenValue`, M)
}
```

DESCRIPTION

```
Depends: Rcpp
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo
```

All Rcpp functions have such an error but they would be fine if I just use sourceCpp("./src/getEigenValue.cpp") instead of using the package.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: What does your NAMESPACE look like

Comment: @JosephWood 
useDynLib(mmds, .registration=TRUE)
importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in your package structure may be foobar'ed here, and we cannot tell what.  @Joseph's comment about the namespace is good too.

Here are a few general comments:

1. Don't use both `#include` files, use only `#include <RcppArmadillo.h>`
2. In a package, don't use `[[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]`
3. Start with a clean slate:

   3.1 Run `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton("mypackage")`
   3.2 Copy your file into `src/`
   3.3 Re-run `compileAttributes()`
   3.4 Build the package

That process works for me:

```
> library("mypackage")
> getEigenValue(cbind(c(1,-1), c(-1,1)))  # same as ?eigen
     [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    2
>
```

I put all relevant files [here](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/stackoverflow/tree/master/65532304/mypackage).

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I tried them and found everything worked once, but after I modified some examples, I got that error message again.

Comment: You must be doing something "special" at your end to possibly "shadow" and hide the working version with a non-working one.  Maybe stop working in a mix of `sourceCpp()` and package work and just update the package -- just a guess.

Comment: @AmberChen, if you could set up a public repo this would be much easier. Also, as Dirk says many times, check out the copious packages on CRAN for more guidance.

Comment: @AmberChen Thanks for accepting the answer. Did you figure out how/why your ride was bumpier than it should have been?  Any tips we should document?

Comment: I apologize that I still have no idea about why these happened, but it seems that a clean  working environment might help. Thank you again!